# Need clarification on how the str.join() method works

Tags: python, string-concatenation

I wrote this code in python:

```py
def master_yoda(text):
    a=text.split()
    a=a[::-1]
    a=" ".join(a)
    return a
```

Which gives the output `'home am I'`
executed with `master_yoda('I am home')`.

Whereas if I put an empty space in between — `a=''.join()a` —
the output becomes `'homeamI'`.
Why does it happen?

Comment: According to the docs [str.join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join). "The separator between elements is the string providing this method." (Whatever the string is before join is the value between each element.)

Comment: Are you asking why joining words together without a space doesn't include spaces in the resulting string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string that invokes the `join` method is used to join the elements, i.e., it appears between each element of the list in the result.

```
>>> "-".join(["a", "b", "c"])
'a-b-c'
>>> "1".join(["a", "b", "c"])
'a1b1c'
>>> "hi".join(["a", "b", "c"])
'ahibhic'
```

The empty string is also a string; it just has 0 characters in it. Therefore, in the result, there are zero characters between each element of the list.

```
>>> "".join(["a", "b", "c"])
'abc'
```